# Deploying a CloudService with DoNotStart specified

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm trying to deploy an Azure *Cloud Service (Classic)* application via VSTS automated builds. I have most things working well for me but I cannot figure out how to get the `Azure Cloud Service Deployment` task to pass the `-DoNotStart` flag to the underlying call to `New-AzureDeployment`. There is an "Additional arguments" field under the collapsed "Advanced Options for Creating New Service" but these seem to only be passed to the `New-AzureService` call and not to the `New-AzureDeployment` call, as best as I can tell.

Any idea how to do this without dropping down to custom PowerShell scripts? I'd really like to not have to maintain PS scripts if I can help it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the source code for [Azure Cloud Service Deployment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureCloudPowerShellDeployment) task, there isn’t the way to specify -DoNotStart parameter.

So, you need to do it through PowerShell scripts, you may consider create a custom build task: [Add a build task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-build-task)

On the other hand, there is a feedback: [DoNotStart parameter for Azure Cloud Service Deployment (New-AzureDeployment)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/4418)

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid of this but wanted to ask since I often miss things (some things being pretty obvious).